# AvalonEdit: how to remove hyperlink underline?

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, avalonedit

I do not want to disable hyperlinks completely (via `Options.EnableHyperlinks`) because I want to be able to open links via `CTRL + Click` but I need to remove underline. How can I do that?

So far I found only `LinkTextForegroundBrush` and `LinkTextBackgroundBrush` in `TextArea.TextView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying AvalonEdit source code a bit to add such option and created a fork/pull request on GitHub. Looks like it was merged into the main repository. https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/pull/10/commits

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this issue.

```
textEditor.TextArea.TextView.LinkTextBackgroundBrush = Brushes.Orange;
textEditor.TextArea.TextView.LinkTextForegroundBrush = Brushes.Black;
textEditor.TextArea.TextView.LinkTextUnderline = false;
```